# Laravel Fortify not instantiable Element (API only)

Tags: fortify

on a new Laravel project I tried to use fortify for authentication. After following the steps in the official documentation and installing fortify as API only (the frontend is separate) I see the Postman calls fail. The calls try to return the corresponding view, while I would like to use Laravel only on the backend side.

1. I have registered FortifyServiceProvider as provider on config/app.php
2. I changed the fortify configuration (fortify.php) in the vendor to indicate that 'view' => false
3. I regenerated the cache with php artisan optimize:clear

However I still get the mentioned error.
I enclose the repository from which it is possible to download the project and I thank anyone who can give me a hand

https://github.com/manghina/laraver-fortify

Comment: The error is: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterViewResponse] is not instantiable